# Configuring openssl on my windows machine

Tags: openssl

I am trying to configure openssl on my windows machine using the following
 command:

`configure -openssl -openssl-linked -I C:\<Open SSL Directory>\include -L C:\<Open SSL Directory>\lib\VC\static OPENSSL_LIBS="-lUser32 -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32" OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG="-lssleay32MDd -llibeay32MDd" OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="-lssleay32MD -llibeay32MD" -opengl desktop -debug-and-release -nomake examples -nomake tests -shared -stl -qt-sql-odbc -qt-style-windows -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-sql-psql -I C:\<Postgre SQL Directory>\include -L C:\<Postgre SQL Directory>\lib.`

However I get the following error:

> target already defined - C (offending arg: OPENSSL_LIBS=-lUser32
>   -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I haven't done this in years, but isn't there a Perl script that will set this up for you? You just tell it VC-WIN32 and shared or static and it generates a makefile called 'NT' for you?

Comment: You should probably avoid making up you own procedures. See [`NOTES.WIN`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN) in the OpenSSL source distribution for the recommended way of configuring and building the library.